# How do i put an XML source into an NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've done this with HTML, like so:

```
NSString *theweatherhtml = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"*URL STRING WOULD GO HERE*"]];
```

But when i do this with an XML file, it returns a 'Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.'

Is there a different way to do this for XML files?

Answer (score 1):

That method is deprecated. You need to use:

```
initWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSMutableDictionary using objectforkey Or NSArray and then convert each value into related varibles. Like -

int value;
value = [[savedStock objectForKey:@"userID"] intValue];